# Parse.com and PhoneGap empty responses

Tags: cordova, parse-platform

I have a simple application that is using the Parse.com javascript SDK. It is working fine while in the browser. But once I package it using PhoneGap build, and test it on a device, none of the Parse requests return a result. A 200 status is returned but the responseText is empty. The weird thing is I essentially copied this code from another one of my apps that works perfectly fine through PhoneGap build.

Any insight on why a request would return empty from parse?

And I can't see why it would work fine in the browser but not in the app.

Here is the simple snippet that is failing. Trying to sign users up also returns the same empty result as this.

```
login: function(data) {

    Parse.User.logIn(data.email, data.password, {
        success: function(user) {
            App.loadController('dashboard');
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
            App.reportParseError(error, user);
        }
    });

},
```

I have verified that the email/username and password are being sent in the request, but Parse just responds empty.

Comment: Hi Justin. I have got the same question as yours. My login codes worked fine in Firefox but did not when deployed on a mobile device.

Comment: @alextc - I actually got mine working last night but am unsure of the solution. Here is what I did, hopefully it works for you then I'll post it as the answer. In PhoneGap Build I disabled debug mode and hydration then rebuilt. Another thing I changed was the access origin. I allowed all for now <access origin="*" />. I did try <access origin="https://api.parse.com" /> too but that was before disabling debug/hydration. So I am unsure if either of these changes fixed it or something else entirely.

Comment: @alextx - One last thing I did right before it started working was from the phonegap build site, I used the QR code downloader at the top right from the App page. Once I installed it using that link, it worked. Please let me know if either of these help you.